# Equivalent of visual-block-mode "I" in visual, visual-line mode

Tags: vimrc

In visual-block mode, it's very convenient to press <kbd>I</kbd> to be able to modify text at the beginning of the selection(s). What is the equivalent way to do this in normal `Visual` mode? For example, the closest I've found is probably something like:

```
[Esc]`<i
```

And I'm not sure there exists a way to do it i `Visual-line` mode? What would be the simplest way to do this: is there a way with a single keystroke like there is in visual-block mode? And the same with `A` to insert (append) at the end of the visual selection(s)?

Comment: See `:h v_o` and `:h v_O`

Comment: @Matt -- sure, but if I'm calling it in a function I don't necessarily know which 'side' I'm on, if I'm to toggle the start/end.

Comment: If used in script then it's not really about "hit"-convenience.

Comment: @Matt -- I see, what's the closest thing (multicursor?) for visual line mode?

Comment: @Matt I see, yea I was going to try to do a keyboard mapping for it if it was possible.

Comment: Typically something like `:'<,'>normal! some_keystrokes`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to have correctly understood, but try this:

```
let s:niceblock_keys = {
    \   '$'  : {'v': 'g$h',      'V': '$',          "\<c-v>": '$h'},
    \   'I'  : {'v': "\<c-v>I",  'V': "\<c-v>^o^I", "\<c-v>": 'I'},
    \   'A'  : {'v': "\<c-v>A",  'V': "\<c-v>0o$A", "\<c-v>": 'A'},
    \   'gI' : {'v': "\<c-v>0I", 'V': "\<c-v>0o$I", "\<c-v>": '0I'},
    \   '>'  : {'v': "\<c-v>>",  'V': "0\<c-v>>",   "\<c-v>": '>'},
    \   '<'  : {'v': "\<c-v><",  'V': "0\<c-v><",   "\<c-v>": '<'},
    \ }
fu s:niceblock(key) abort
    return s:niceblock_keys[a:key][mode()]
endfu

xno <expr> $  <sid>niceblock('$')
xno <expr> I  <sid>niceblock('I')
xno <expr> gI <sid>niceblock('gI')
xno <expr> A  <sid>niceblock('A')
xno <expr> >  <sid>niceblock('>')
xno <expr> <  <sid>niceblock('<')
```

Adapted from the [vim-niceblock](https://github.com/kana/vim-niceblock) plugin.